# the input submit is outside of Form into div

Tags: html, css, grid

I want to create a div container who contain a form, but I have the input submit outside of the container div

```css
.container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #E1291B;
  display: grid;
  background-color: bisque;
}

.form-login {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  gap: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
    <h4>Connectez vous</h4>
  </div>
  <form class="form-login" action="">
    <label for="email">E-mail</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="">
    <label for="pass">Mot de passe   </label>
    <input type="password" name="pass" id="">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: don't use percentage with gap, that's your issue

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Give `min-height` to `.form-login` class. Also you can give `.container` `width:max-width` instead of width that way .container will occupy width according to the width of content inside it.

```css
.container {
  margin: auto;
  width: max-content; /*insted of 20%*/
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #E1291B;
  display: grid;
  background-color: bisque;
  height:max-content;
}

.form-login {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  gap: 10%;
  min-height:160px; /* give min-height of 160px or more */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
    <h4>Connectez vous</h4>
  </div>
  <form class="form-login" action="">
    <label for="email">E-mail</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="">
    <label for="pass">Mot de passe   </label>
    <input type="password" name="pass" id="">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: @mplungjan Yes and that because the code posted by the owner contains `width:20%` and which is why i have suggested him to use `width:max-content`.

Comment: So why not add it?

Comment: So the issue is actually the % in `gap: 10%;`  and a missing min-width

Comment: @mplungjan i just did. I did not want him to get confused and stick to his main concern which was related to height.

Comment: @mplungjan yes but if he wants to keep the `gap:10%` then we will have to use fixed height.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should add `min-width` to the .container div to prevent it from getting too narrow:

```css
.container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 20%;
  min-width: 170px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #E1291B;
  display: grid;
  background-color: bisque;
}

.form-login {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  gap: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
    <h4>Connectez vous</h4>
  </div>
  <form class="form-login" action="">
    <label for="email">E-mail</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="">
    <label for="pass">Mot de passe   </label>
    <input type="password" name="pass" id="">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
  </form>
</div>
```

You could also put `width: 96%` (for example) in the inputs to make them grow based on the div size:

```css
.form-login input  {
  width: 96%;
}
```

Comment: Run the snippet here (in Chrome) and the login is still outside

Comment: the issue is actually the % in gap: 10%; and a missing min-width

Comment: Is that so? It works to me in firefox.